# Hiding file using image LSB Steganography

Tags: java, steganography

I hide the file bytes into LSB or upper layers of an image using this Steganography class.
the original class is in **C#** but i convert it to **java** for project needs
but after conversion when i run it, I have **out of range error** when convert byte to **boolean[]** and vise versa using **bytetobool()** and **booltobyte()** methods.because **R,G,B** values must be (0-255).
how i can solve this error?

```
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.awt.Image;
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.nio.file.Path;
   import java.nio.file.Files;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayDeque;
   import java.util.Deque;

   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

   public class Steganography
   {
   public int height, width, fileNameSize;
   public long FSize;
   String FilePath,ImagePath,fNameWext;
   BufferedImage newimage=null,CoverImage=null;
   byte[] bytestobehidden;
   FileInputStream EncryptedStream=null;
   public Steganography (String imagepath)
   {
      try
      {
       ImagePath=imagepath;
       File imagefile=new File(ImagePath);
       newimage=ImageIO.read(imagefile);
       CoverImage=newimage;
       //CoverImage=new BufferedImage(newimage.getWidth(),newimage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {e.printStackTrace();}

   }
   public static boolean[] byteToBoolArr(byte x) {
        boolean[] boolArr = new boolean[8];
        boolArr[0] = ((x & 0x01) != 0);
        boolArr[1] = ((x & 0x02) != 0);
        boolArr[2] = ((x & 0x04) != 0);
        boolArr[3] = ((x & 0x08) != 0);

        boolArr[4] = ((x & 0x10) != 0);
        boolArr[5] = ((x & 0x20) != 0);
        boolArr[6] = ((x & 0x40) != 0);
        boolArr[7] = ((x & 0x80) != 0);
        return boolArr;
    }
   public final void byte2bool(byte inp, tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> outp)
    {
        if (inp >= 0 && inp <= 255)
            {
                    for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                            if (inp % 2 == 1)
                            {
                                    outp.argValue[i] = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    outp.argValue[i] = false;
                            }
                            inp /= 2;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Input number is illegal.");
            }

    }



    public  byte bool2byte(boolean[] inp)
    {

        byte outp = 0;
        for (short i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (inp[i])
            {

                outp += (byte)Math.pow(2.0, (double)(7 - i));
            }
        }
        return outp;
    }

    public void StegoLayer(long FileSize, String filepath, String saveimage, byte[] encryptedbytes) throws IOException
    {
       height = CoverImage.getHeight();
   width = CoverImage.getWidth();
       //BMPMetadata bmpimage=new BMPMetadata(CoverImage);
       File bmpfile = new File(saveimage);
    ImageIO.write(CoverImage,"BMP",bmpfile);
            BufferedImage bmpimage=new BufferedImage(CoverImage.getWidth(),CoverImage.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            bmpimage=ImageIO.read(bmpfile);
       //Bitmap loadedTrueBitmap = new Bitmap(loadedImage);
       bytestobehidden = encryptedbytes;
               //EncryptedStream=encryptedbytes;
       FSize = FileSize;

       FilePath = filepath;
               File f=new File(FilePath);
              //String fileName=f.getName();
              fNameWext = f.getName();
        int pos = fNameWext.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos > 0 && pos < (fNameWext.length() - 1)) { // If '.' is not the first or last character.
           fNameWext = fNameWext.substring(0, pos);
        }
            fileNameSize=fNameWext.length();

        //fileNameSize = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath).length();
            BufferedImage stegoBitmap = StegoLayer(8, bmpimage, 0, (height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - fileNameSize - 1, true);
            FSize -= (height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - fileNameSize - 1;
            if (FSize > 0)
            {
                    for (int i = 7; i >= 0 && FSize > 0; i--)
                    {
                            stegoBitmap = StegoLayer(i, stegoBitmap, (((8 - i) * height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - fileNameSize - (8 - i)), (((9 - i) * height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - fileNameSize - (9 - i)), false);
                            FSize -= (height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1;
                    }
            }

            ImageIO.write(stegoBitmap, "BMP", bmpfile);

    }


    public BufferedImage StegoLayer(int layer, BufferedImage inputBitmap, long startPosition, long endPosition, boolean writeFileName)
    {
        BufferedImage outputBitmap = inputBitmap;
        layer--;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        long fileSize = FSize;
        long FNSize = 0;
        boolean[] t = new boolean[8];
        boolean[] rb = new boolean[8];
        boolean[] gb = new boolean[8];
        boolean[] bb = new boolean[8];
        Color pixel = null;
        byte r, g, b;

        if (writeFileName)
        {
            FNSize = fileNameSize;
            //String fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath);

            //write fileName:
            for (i = 0; i < height && i * (height / 3) < fileNameSize; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < (width / 3) * 3 && i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) < fileNameSize; j++)
                {
                    int z=i * (height / 3) + j / 3;
                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_t = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(t);
                    byte2bool((byte)fNameWext.charAt(z), tempRef_t);

    //                         t=byteToBoolArr((byte)fNameWext.charAt(z));
                    pixel = new Color(inputBitmap.getRGB(j, i));
                    r = (byte)pixel.getRed();
                    g = (byte)pixel.getGreen();
                    b = (byte)pixel.getBlue();
                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_rb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(rb);
                    byte2bool(r, tempRef_rb);
                    rb = tempRef_rb.argValue;

   //                        rb=byteToBoolArr(r);

                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_gb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(gb);
                    byte2bool(g, tempRef_gb);
                    gb = tempRef_gb.argValue;

  //                        gb=byteToBoolArr(g);

                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_bb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(bb);
                    byte2bool(b, tempRef_bb);
                    bb = tempRef_bb.argValue;

   //                        bb=byteToBoolArr(b);

                    if (j % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        rb[7] = t[0];
                        gb[7] = t[1];
                        bb[7] = t[2];
                    }
                    else if (j % 3 == 1)
                    {
                        rb[7] = t[3];
                        gb[7] = t[4];
                        bb[7] = t[5];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rb[7] = t[6];
                        gb[7] = t[7];
                    }

                    Color result = new Color((int)bool2byte(rb), (int)bool2byte(gb), (int)bool2byte(bb));
                    outputBitmap.setRGB(j, i, result.getRGB());
                }
            i--;
        }
        //write file (after file name):
        int tempj = j;

        for (; i < height && i * (height / 3) < endPosition - startPosition + FNSize && startPosition + i * (height / 3) < fileSize + FNSize; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < (width / 3) * 3 && i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) < endPosition - startPosition + FNSize && startPosition + i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) < fileSize + FNSize; j++)
            {
                if (tempj != 0)
                {
                    j = tempj;
                    tempj = 0;
                }
                 tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_t = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(t);
                 long k=startPosition + i * (height / 3) + j / 3 - FNSize;
                byte2bool(bytestobehidden[(int)k], tempRef_t);

                 pixel = new Color(inputBitmap.getRGB(j, i));
                    r = (byte)pixel.getRed();
                    g = (byte)pixel.getGreen();
                    b = (byte)pixel.getBlue();
                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_rb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(rb);
                    byte2bool(r, tempRef_rb);
                    rb = tempRef_rb.argValue;

       //                         rb=byteToBoolArr(r);

                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_gb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(gb);
                    byte2bool(g, tempRef_gb);
                    gb = tempRef_gb.argValue;
       //                        gb=byteToBoolArr(g);

                    tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_bb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(bb);
                    byte2bool(b, tempRef_bb);
                    bb = tempRef_bb.argValue;

   //                         bb=byteToBoolArr(b);

                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    rb[layer] = t[0];
                    gb[layer] = t[1];
                    bb[layer] = t[2];
                }
                else if (j % 3 == 1)
                {
                    rb[layer] = t[3];
                    gb[layer] = t[4];
                    bb[layer] = t[5];
                }
                else
                {
                    rb[layer] = t[6];
                    gb[layer] = t[7];
                }
                Color result =new Color((int)bool2byte(rb), (int)bool2byte(gb), (int)bool2byte(bb));
                outputBitmap.setRGB(j, i, result.getRGB());

            }
        long tempFS = fileSize, tempFNS = fileNameSize;
        r = (byte)(tempFS % 100);
        tempFS /= 100;
        g = (byte)(tempFS % 100);
        tempFS /= 100;
        b = (byte)(tempFS % 100);
        Color flenColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        outputBitmap.setRGB(width - 1, height - 1, flenColor.getRGB());

        r = (byte)(tempFNS % 100);
        tempFNS /= 100;
        g = (byte)(tempFNS % 100);
        tempFNS /= 100;
        b = (byte)(tempFNS % 100);
        Color fnlenColor =new Color(r, g, b);
        outputBitmap.setRGB(width - 2, height - 1, fnlenColor.getRGB());

        return outputBitmap;
    }
    public byte[] ExtractLayer(tangible.RefObject<String> ExtFName)
    {
        height = CoverImage.getHeight();
    width = CoverImage.getWidth();

       BufferedImage StegoBitmap = CoverImage;
        int i, j = 0;
        boolean[] t = new boolean[8];
        boolean[] rb = new boolean[8];
        boolean[] gb = new boolean[8];
        boolean[] bb = new boolean[8];
        Color pixel =null;
        byte r, g, b;
        pixel = new Color(StegoBitmap.getRGB(width - 1, height - 1));
        long fSize = pixel.getRed() + pixel.getGreen() * 100 + pixel.getBlue() * 10000;
        pixel = new Color(StegoBitmap.getRGB(width - 2, height - 1));
        long fNameSize = pixel.getRed() + pixel.getGreen() * 100 + pixel.getBlue() * 10000;
        byte[] ExtBytes = new byte[(int)fSize];
        //tangible.RefObject<String> tempRef_t = new tangible.RefObject<String>(ExtFName);

    ExtFName.argValue = "";
        byte temp;

        //Read file name:
        for (i = 0; i < height && i * (height / 3) < fNameSize; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < (width / 3) * 3 && i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) < fNameSize; j++)
            {
                pixel = new Color(StegoBitmap.getRGB(j, i));
                r = (byte)pixel.getRed();
                g = (byte)pixel.getGreen();
                b = (byte)pixel.getBlue();;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_rb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(rb);
                byte2bool(r, tempRef_rb);
                rb = tempRef_rb.argValue;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_gb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(gb);
                byte2bool(g, tempRef_gb);
                gb = tempRef_gb.argValue;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_bb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(bb);
                byte2bool(b, tempRef_bb);
                bb = tempRef_bb.argValue;


                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    t[0] = rb[7];
                    t[1] = gb[7];
                    t[2] = bb[7];
                }
                else if (j % 3 == 1)
                {
                    t[3] = rb[7];
                    t[4] = gb[7];
                    t[5] = bb[7];
                }
                else
                {
                    t[6] = rb[7];
                    t[7] = gb[7];
                    temp = bool2byte(t);
                    ExtFName.argValue += (char)temp;
                }
            }

        //Read file on layer 8 (after file name):
        int tempj = j;
        i--;

        for (; i < height && i * (height / 3) < fSize + fNameSize; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < (width / 3) * 3 && i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) < (height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1 && i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) < fSize + fNameSize; j++)
            {
                if (tempj != 0)
                {
                    j = tempj;
                    tempj = 0;
                }
                pixel = new Color(StegoBitmap.getRGB(j, i));
                r = (byte)pixel.getRed();
                g = (byte)pixel.getGreen();
                b = (byte)pixel.getBlue();;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_rb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(rb);
                byte2bool(r, tempRef_rb);
                rb = tempRef_rb.argValue;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_gb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(gb);
                byte2bool(g, tempRef_gb);
                gb = tempRef_gb.argValue;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_bb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(bb);
                byte2bool(b, tempRef_bb);
                bb = tempRef_bb.argValue;

                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    t[0] = rb[7];
                    t[1] = gb[7];
                    t[2] = bb[7];
                }
                else if (j % 3 == 1)
                {
                    t[3] = rb[7];
                    t[4] = gb[7];
                    t[5] = bb[7];
                }
                else
                {
                    t[6] = rb[7];
                    t[7] = gb[7];
                    temp = bool2byte(t);
                    ExtBytes[(int)(i * (height / 3) + j / 3 - fNameSize)] = temp;
                }
            }

        //Read file on other layers:
        long readedOnL8 = (height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - fNameSize - 1;

        for (int layer = 6; layer >= 0 && readedOnL8 + (6 - layer) * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1) < fSize; layer--)
            for (i = 0; i < height && i * (height / 3) + readedOnL8 + (6 - layer) * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1) < fSize; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < (width / 3) * 3 && i * (height / 3) + (j / 3) + readedOnL8 + (6 - layer) * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1) < fSize; j++)
                {
                 pixel = new Color(StegoBitmap.getRGB(j, i));
                r = (byte)pixel.getRed();
                g = (byte)pixel.getGreen();
                b = (byte)pixel.getBlue();;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_rb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(rb);
                byte2bool(r, tempRef_rb);
                rb = tempRef_rb.argValue;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_gb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(gb);
                byte2bool(g, tempRef_gb);
                gb = tempRef_gb.argValue;
                tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> tempRef_bb = new tangible.RefObject<boolean[]>(bb);
                byte2bool(b, tempRef_bb);
                bb = tempRef_bb.argValue;

                    if (j % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        t[0] = rb[layer];
                        t[1] = gb[layer];
                        t[2] = bb[layer];
                    }
                    else if (j % 3 == 1)
                    {
                        t[3] = rb[layer];
                        t[4] = gb[layer];
                        t[5] = bb[layer];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t[6] = rb[layer];
                        t[7] = gb[layer];
                        temp = bool2byte(t);
                        long k=i * (height / 3) + j / 3 + (6 - layer) * ((height * (width / 3) * 3) / 3 - 1) + readedOnL8;
                        ExtBytes[(int)k] = temp;
                    }
                }
        return ExtBytes;

    }
}
```

[this the whole stack error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCab4.png)

Comment: Please post whole stack trace of error

Comment: i added the stack error to my question

Comment: Even if any of the answers have resolved your problem, please consider improving your question for the benefit of future reads. Trim your code to the shortest snippet that replicates the problem, also referred to as [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The stack error should also be included here as text and not referred to other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the method `byte2bool()` (as the stacktrace says):

```
public final void byte2bool(byte inp, tangible.RefObject<boolean[]> outp) {
    if (inp >= 0 && inp <= 255)
```

`byte` in Java is always signed and therefore in the range `-128` to `127`. A comparision to 255 leads to such an error.

Comment: Is there any solution to make the byte be unsigned in java?

Comment: You can either use byte unsigned when using hey digits (like in your `byteToBoolArr()`) or use another datatype (e.g. `short` or `int`).

Comment: the problem that i need ’ byte ’ to represent the image pixel and edit it, is there any method to access image pixel **LSB** without any need to use byte ?

Comment: Your code will also work if you drop the first check (the one shown in my answer).